# Blackberry - Where is SQLite Database stored?

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, cordova

I am using SQLite and phonegap to create a multi platform app. However, I have run across an issue.

I am looking at opening a database which I have pre-populated using the SQLite Manager plugin. However, I am now looking for the location the phonegap stores the database files named '0000000000000001.db' and 'database.db'

I have found this for iPhone and Android, however cannot seem to get the location for the blackberry, Could someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the database location in Blackberry while using phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278689/what-is-the-database-location-in-blackberry-while-using-phonegap)