# What is the database location in Blackberry while using phonegap

Tags: database, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator

I have a 9800 simulator.
I mounted a directory as SDcard...

Now if i use

```
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Then where will my database gets stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to mount the SD card before installing the application and then i should execute my application...